# NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005) on Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: virtualbox

My OS: **Ubuntu 20.04LTS**
Software: **Virtualbox 6.1**

Virtualbox worked well until today. Today I ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade`. After all updates were installed it was no longer possible to start a virtual machine in VirtualBox. Immediately after starting VirtualBox I get the following message:

```
Het is niet gelukt een sessie te openen voor virtuele machine Caine11.

Failed to load R0 module /usr/lib/virtualbox/ExtensionPacks/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack/linux.amd64/VBoxEhciR0.r0: RTLdrGetBits failed (VERR_SYMBOL_VALUE_TOO_BIG).
    
Failed to load ring-0 module 'VBoxEhciR0.r0' for device 'usb-ehci' (VERR_SYMBOL_VALUE_TOO_BIG).
    
Resultaatcode: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: ConsoleWrap
Interface: IConsole {872da645-4a9b-1727-bee2-5585105b9eed}
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve the problem myself today. The error message was telling me that the version of VirtualBox and the version of the extensions were different.

Go to **Preferences > Extensions**

Remove the extensions

Download the latest extension pack from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Install the up to date extension pack

Now VirtualBox works perfectly again.

Comment: As you have managed to find a solution, please don't forget to mark your answer as the accepted answer.