# Cannot run Virtualbox 6.1.38_Ubuntu r153438 on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox

I cannot not run a virtual machine in Virtubalbox anymore. I already made an apt purge virtualbox* and removed all virtualbox files in the HD. Reinstall it, create a new VM but keeps giving the error:

```
The virtual machine 'windows 10' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
MachineWrap
IMachine {85632c68-b5bb-4316-a900-5eb28d3413df}
```

Since it is a new installation, i tried to install the corresponding Extension Pack but again gives an error:

```
Failed to install the Extension Pack /home/hiro/Transferências/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.38.vbox-extpack.
The installer failed with exit code 1: VBoxExtPackHelperApp: error: The owner is not root: '/usr'.
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
ExtPackManagerWrap
IExtPackManager {70401eef-c8e9-466b-9660-45cb3e9979e4}
```

I tried to check others posts like this [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1311800/ns-error-failure-0x80004005-on-ubuntu-20-04lts) but it does not help.
This happened from some upgrade in Ubuntu.
Any suggestions?
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:
I gave up. I used the virt-manager instead. Thanks.

Comment: "*I already made an apt purge virtualbox and removed all virtualbox files in the HD*" Does that include all your Vbox files inside your /home directory? Apt won't remove those automatically. You must do that manually. If the issue persists across a purge-and-reinstall, then inside /home is the place to look.

Comment: I did not remove the virtual machine but when i reinstall it, i choose a diferent directory and i tried to create a new virtual machine. Still gaves errors.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you do not have virtualization enabled in your BIOS? You want to look for VT-x, AMD-V, SVM, Intel VT-d, or somesuch in your BIOS. If such an option is available, be sure that "enabled" is selected.

See this page for instructions: [Enabling Virtualization in your PC BIOS](https://bce.berkeley.edu/enabling-virtualization-in-your-pc-bios.html)

Apologies if that seems basic, but I had trouble with that once, when I reset my BIOS to default settings.

Comment: I have the virtualization enabled in the BIOS. Please note that Virtualbox was working fine. Only after Ubuntu made some updates, the Virtualbox stopped working. Thanks.